# Advice on openMP implementation

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp, reduction

I have previously been working with openMP in relatively simple situations. As I'm not that experience yet, I need some advice on how to best use openMP in my below code.

Basically my code numerically integrates two vectors (*up* and *un*) forward in time by solving two coupled differential equations using a Runge-Kutta 4th order scheme - i.e. for every step forward in time four temporary steps are made:

```
#define DUDT_P(STEP)     cmplx(0,1)*(   d(rng_0,1)*CONJG(un(rng_p1,STEP))*un(rng_p2,STEP) + \
                                        d(rng_0,2)*CONJG(un(rng_m1,STEP))*up(rng_p1,STEP) + \
                                        d(rng_0,3)*      un(rng_m2,STEP) *up(rng_m1,STEP) )

#define DUDT_N(STEP)     cmplx(0,1)*(   d(rng_0,1)*CONJG(up(rng_p1,STEP))*up(rng_p2,STEP) + \
                                        d(rng_0,2)*CONJG(up(rng_m1,STEP))*un(rng_p1,STEP) + \
                                        d(rng_0,3)*      up(rng_m2,STEP) *un(rng_m1,STEP) )

[...]

do ii = 2, nt+1 
        do jj = 1,nti

                ! ---------- STEP 1/4 ---------- THERE MUST BE A BARRIER/CONSISTENT MEMORY VIEW HERE
                dup(rng_0,1) = DUDT_P(1)
                up(:,2) = up(:,1) + dt2*dup(:,1)  

                dun(rng_0,1) = DUDT_N(1) 
                un(:,2) = un(:,1) + dt2*dun(:,1)

                ! ---------- STEP 2/4 ---------- THERE MUST BE A BARRIER/CONSISTENT MEMORY VIEW HERE
                dup(rng_0,2) = DUDT_P(2)
                up(:,3) = up(:,1) + dt2*dup(:,2)

                dun(rng_0,2) = DUDT_N(2)
                un(:,3) = un(:,1) + dt2*dun(:,2)

                ! ---------- STEP 3/4 ---------- THERE MUST BE A BARRIER/CONSISTENT MEMORY VIEW HERE
                dup(rng_0,3) = DUDT_P(3)
                up(:,4) = up(:,1) + dt*dup(:,3)

                dun(rng_0,3) = DUDT_N(3)
                un(:,4) = un(:,1) + dt*dun(:,3)

                ! ---------- STEP 4/4 ---------- THERE MUST BE A BARRIER/CONSISTENT MEMORY VIEW HERE
                dup(rng_0,4) = DUDT_P(4)
                up(:,1) = up(:,1) + dt6*dup(:,1) + dt3*dup(:,2) + dt3*dup(:,3) + dt6*dup(:,4) ! Full/actual time stepped solution (full RK4 solution)

                dun(rng_0,4) = DUDT_N(4)
                un(:,1) = un(:,1) + dt6*dun(:,1) + dt3*dun(:,2) + dt3*dun(:,3) + dt6*dun(:,4) ! Full/actual time stepped solution (full RK4 solution)

        end do

        saved(:,ii,1) = up(:,1) ! Save solution
        saved(:,ii,2) = un(:,1)
end do
```

Now, since each vector is 20 components large, there are a lot of arithmetic operations needed per temporary time step. 
You can see this by looking at the derivative *DUDT_P()* and *DUDT_N()* (macro) functions, one for each vector, and notice that they involve element-wise arithmetic in the *rng_** entries between the vectors (here all *rng_** lists specify various of the 20 elements in the *up* and *un* vectors).

There is one important constraint, which I have also commented in the code. Since the solution at each following temporary time step depends on the previous, the threads MUST have the same updated view on the *up* and *un* vectors before calculating the next temp. time step solution (i.e. shared).

For clarity on the variables, this is my used notation:

- d(:,:) are constant (parameter) interaction coefs.
- up(1:20,1) and un(1:20,1) are the presently known actual solutions
- up(1:20,2) and un(1:20,2) are the first temp. time step solutions
- up(1:20,3) and un(1:20,3) are the second temp. time step solutions
- up(1:20,4) and un(1:20,4) are the third temp. time step solutions
- The structure of the real and temp. solutions need not necessarily be in the up(1:20,1:4) format I have chosen here.
- The memory view on the *dup* and *dun* rate of change variables must be consistent at the point during step 4/4, where they are used to calculate the final/real time step solution.

I have thought of a couple ways to tackle this, however, I'm stuck in both:

1. At each of the four temp. steps, one thread could calculate *DUDT_P()* and the other *DUDT_N()* by making two sections for each temp step. However, when trying this there is a small performance loss because, I'm guessing, that *dup* and *dun* (like *up* and *un*) need to be shared vars since there is no way of specifying which thread is to execute which of the two sections? I.e. the cached *dup* and *dun* become invalid unless the same thread can somehow be forced to only do the calculations at each temp step for the same vector.
2. Somehow establish a work-sharing situation or using a reduction clause at each temp step, however, I have difficulty understanding how to set this up.

Thanks for any comment you may have!

Comment: If you remove the array syntax and you write explicitly the innermost do loop (just after the do jj), your memory accesses may be better because you will have less cache misses. The array syntax makes one loop per line, so you may empty your cache every time.

Comment: @AnthonyScemama: So basically writing out the innermost loop for the array syntax for each of the four steps, and then wrap them in something like `!$OMP DO SCHEDULE(STATIC)`?

Comment: Yes, but don't do the openmp on the innermost loop. It's too short.

Comment: I guess what Anthony wants say is that go columnwise instead of row-wise since Fortran calls cache lines columnwise. I don't think there is any need of separate inner loops just to improve efficiency. Isn't it?

Comment: @AnthonyScemama, thanks. Do maybe have suggestion as to how I could make the code run parallel? I tried the OMP DO, but I get slower performance when using more than two cores/threads compared to running it serial, as you correctly stated.

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar, I tried implementing his suggestion and, and it made a slight improvement (when running the code without openMP), however, since the integration is LONG, this will actually sum up to quite a bit. Do you have any suggestions as to implementing some openMP functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Single-core optimization

- You have a very good ADD/MUL balance. On this kind of CPU-bound code, ifort or PGI may give a better performance than gfortran. Are you using such a compiler?
  Have you activated the best compiler options for your CPU (`-xAVX`, `-xCORE-AVX2`, `-xSSE4.2`, etc) ? This could make a lot of difference on your particular example.
- If you put explicitly the loop boundaries : `do k=1,20`,
  the compiler will know what to best for the loops.
- You could also play on memory alignment. With the Intel compiler, you
  can put the directive:

  `!DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIGN : 32 :: dup, up, dun, un`

  after the declaration of your variables. It is also possible with the PGI compiler. This will improve the memory access, and the vectorization possibilities of the compiler, as you can only vectorize with data aligned
  on a 32 byte boundary (or 64 bytes on Xeon Phi, and 16 bytes on older CPUs).
- As your first dimension is 20, all the columns of your array are also 32-byte
  aligned. You can tell this to the compiler using the directive `!DIR$ VECTOR ALIGNED`
  before the inner-most loop.
- Try `-O2` instead of `-O3`, as `-O3` is sometimes slower.
- Try the flush-to-zero compiler option : working with denormalized numbers slows down the execution

### OpenMP

If you want to use one thread for `up` and one thread for `un`, you could try the following,
but I'm really not sure you will gain (or event not lose...) because of the openMP barriers.

Thread 0 is doing `up` and thread 1 is doing `un`. It is important to put the `allocate`
statements and initialization inside the openMP sections so that the memory is allocated as close as possible
to the threads (first-touch policy).

---

Here your code modified with all those ideas:

```
!DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIGN : 32 :: dup, up, dun, un

#define DUDT_P(STEP)     cmplx(0,1)*(   d(rng_0,1)*CONJG(un(rng_p1,STEP))*un(rng_p2,STEP) + \
                                        d(rng_0,2)*CONJG(un(rng_m1,STEP))*up(rng_p1,STEP) + \
                                        d(rng_0,3)*      un(rng_m2,STEP) *up(rng_m1,STEP) )

#define DUDT_N(STEP)     cmplx(0,1)*(   d(rng_0,1)*CONJG(up(rng_p1,STEP))*up(rng_p2,STEP) + \
                                        d(rng_0,2)*CONJG(up(rng_m1,STEP))*un(rng_p1,STEP) + \
                                        d(rng_0,3)*      up(rng_m2,STEP) *un(rng_m1,STEP) )

[...]

!$OMP PARALLEL SHARED( up,un,dup,dun, [...] ) PRIVATE( [...] ) num_threads(2)
ithread = omp_get_thread_num()

!DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIGN : 32 :: dup, up, dun, un
if (ithread == 0) then
  allocate (up(1:20,4), dup(1:20,4))
  ! Initialization is important to pin the memory to the cores
  up = 0.
  dun = 0.
else
  allocate (un(1:20,4), dun(1:20,4))
  ! Initialization is important to pin the memory to the cores
  un = 0.
  dun = 0.
endif

do ii = 2, nt+1
        do jj = 1,nti

            !$OMP BARRIER
                ! ---------- STEP 1/4 ---------- THERE MUST BE A BARRIER/CONSISTENT MEMORY VIEW HERE
            if (ithread == 0) then
                dup(rng_0,1) = DUDT_P(1)
                !DIR$ VECTOR ALIGNED
                do k=1,20
                  up(k,2) = up(k,1) + dt2*dup(k,1)
                end do
            else
                dun(rng_0,1) = DUDT_N(1)
                !DIR$ VECTOR ALIGNED
                do k=1,20
                  un(k,2) = un(k,1) + dt2*dun(k,1)
                end do
            endif

            !$OMP BARRIER
                ! ---------- STEP 2/4 ---------- THERE MUST BE A BARRIER/CONSISTENT MEMORY VIEW HERE
            if (ithread == 0) then
                dup(rng_0,2) = DUDT_P(2)
                !DIR$ VECTOR ALIGNED
                do k=1,20
                  up(k,3) = up(k,1) + dt2*dup(k,2)
                end do
            else
                dun(rng_0,2) = DUDT_N(2)
                !DIR$ VECTOR ALIGNED
                do k=1,20
                  un(k,3) = un(k,1) + dt2*dun(k,2)
                end do
            endif

            !$OMP BARRIER
                ! ---------- STEP 3/4 ---------- THERE MUST BE A BARRIER/CONSISTENT MEMORY VIEW HERE
            if (ithread == 0) then
                dup(rng_0,3) = DUDT_P(3)
                !DIR$ VECTOR ALIGNED
                do k=1,20
                  up(k,4) = up(k,1) + dt*dup(k,3)
                end do
            else
                dun(rng_0,3) = DUDT_N(3)
                !DIR$ VECTOR ALIGNED
                do k=1,20
                  un(k,4) = un(k,1) + dt*dun(k,3)
                end do
            endif

            !$OMP BARRIER
                ! ---------- STEP 4/4 ---------- THERE MUST BE A BARRIER/CONSISTENT MEMORY VIEW HERE
            if (ithread == 0) then
                dup(rng_0,4) = DUDT_P(4)
                !DIR$ VECTOR ALIGNED
                do k=1,20
                  up(k,1) = up(k,1) + dt6*dup(k,1) + dt3*dup(k,2) + dt3*dup(k,3) + dt6*dup(k,4) ! Full/actual time stepped solution (full RK4 solution)
                enddo
            else
                dun(rng_0,4) = DUDT_N(4)
                !DIR$ VECTOR ALIGNED
                do k=1,20
                  un(k,1) = un(k,1) + dt6*dun(k,1) + dt3*dun(k,2) + dt3*dun(k,3) + dt6*dun(k,4) ! Full/actual time stepped solution (full RK4 solution)
                enddo
            endif

        end do

        if (ithread == 0) then

          do k=1,20
            saved(k,ii,1) = up(k,1) ! Save solution
          end do

        else

          do k=1,20
            saved(k,ii,2) = un(k,1) ! Save solution
          end do

        end if

end do

if (ithread == 0) then
  deallocate(un,up,dun,dup)
end if

!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Comment: Could you explain the first touch policy and why to allocate in the parallel region?

Comment: It's all explained here : http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2513149 and here : https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~phjk/Publications/Proxies...HPCS98.pdf

Comment: Does it have any effect on the most common single or two CPU nodes in a distributed memory cluster? I accept it could be important on an Altix. Does it make any difference on your tests for the code in your answer?

Comment: On Intel single sockets, it doesn't have any effect. You can see a small effect on dual sockets, as well as AMD 12-core CPUs which are two 6-cores on one chip. On Altix UV, there is a huge difference. I didn't compile the code in my answer. @nicholasr may tell us if it is important ;-)

Comment: @AnthonyScemama, I can't thank you enough for your help. The single-core optimsations gave a performance gain of ~10-100 times! Since I previously used gfortran with only -O2, I found by experimenting with the Intel compiler several advantages: 1) Better use of the instruction set, 2) the intel compiler unlike GNU's is able to vectorise operations on the double complex type, and 3) explicitly allowing to align data structures. However, in this integration I actually need to include the denormalised values in the calculation, as they otherwise give rise to large numerical dissipation over time.

Comment: @AnthonyScemama and Vladimir, Regarding multithreading I found a small performance loss using the above approach. I found that this is due to the overhead of the barriers compared to the between-barrier workload (basically the inner loops are to small). As I do not yet know if this will be run on a single socket or some distributed memory system I didn't experiment with Anthony's suggestion of allocating memory "locally".

Comment: Happy to see that it helped :-)